# How to efficiently and clearly parse a custom binary format in Python?

Tags: python, linux, networking

*Note: this is not a dup of any question that I have found here. The "obvious" solutions that were provided unfortunately do not apply here*

---

I have a custom protocol with custom bytes.

And I have another protocol with other custom bytes.

And I have another protocol with yet other custom bytes.

(I guess you get the situation)

**I want to parse them from Python.**

---

Python is Turing-complete, so this is possible. However this is slow and the relevant libraries (e.g. `struct` or `xdrlib`) are far too slow: I am not dissecting a few packets, I am coding clients to interface to high-performance servers. Plus these libs are really not intended to be used in parallel. So this was the first problem: **I need speed**.

There is also a second problem: C for instance is Turing-complete and can be executed from Python. C can be made fast enough without much work. However coding *many* complete protocols in a language such as C (or even Python actually) is dreadful: *when someone presents a protocol, it is done with tables, sometimes simple structs, often using a DSL*. They don't use C nor Python because it is not as easily readable. I'm not talking about parsing a GIF file here in a pet project. I'm talking about exchanging data using different protocols with different servers: easily describing the structure and internal relationships would really be a huge help. So this was the second problem: **I need clarity and reusability**.

Some messaging/serialization/RPC libraries, such as Cap'n Proto, Protobuf or MsgPack for instance are both **fast, clear and reusable** (coded in a low level language and implementing a DSL). The problem is that I have no control over the binary protocol nor over the specific messaging algorithm: I cannot just plug one of them in the system, declare a schema and call it a day. That won't work. Moreover their DSLs is often not expressive enough to include conditions in the schema for example.

**So, considering all that, how would you implement a fast binary parser usable from Python while keeping the whole code extremely clear and reusable (what other library solve by providing a DSL)?**

Comment: You kinda have the answer in the question: build your own fast, clear and reusable library for your protocol.

Comment: Protocol**S**. With a few of them talking in similar but slightly incompatible dialects. I could write my own but I can't believe that it does not exist yet: I am not the first who has to implement a binary parser and I really don't think that people would reimplement everything from scratch each time. I may not have searched in the right places with the right words though.

Comment: Well at some point you'll have to bite the bullet: either you do it in C and it's fast or you do it in python and it's more flexible. You may interleave both as you see fit (for instance invoke python hooks at specific points), but the languages will not merge magically.

Comment: Maybe implement parser in [cython](http://cython.org) + [hammer](https://github.com/abiggerhammer/hammer) ?

Comment: So people do **really** start from scratch each time they have something to parse?! Oo.  No tools to generate such a code, people have to do it manually each time... Lucky the ones who can use MsgPack!

Comment: @AndreyT: Yeah, Cython was what I was actually thinking about if I really have to use a general purpose language to express my format structure and constraints...

Comment: Hammer looks like a good suggestion (it is such a shame that it has no Python 3 support though).